# Getting 'error: syntax error at or near...' in Postgresql insert query

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, express

I'm fairly new at Postgresql and learning new things everyday. So I have this blog project where I want to use PostgreSQL as a db. But I'm kind of stuck at the most basic insert query which is throwing an error. I have three tables, `posts`, `authors` and `categories`. I could create the table properly I guess but when I try to insert data I get this error:

```
error: syntax error at or near 
length: 95,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '42601',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: '122',
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'scan.l',
  line: '1180',
  routine: 'scanner_yyerror'
```

Now I don't know where the issue is and Postgres' errors are not that specific.

Can anyone please tell me where I could be going wrong?

Here are the tables:

```
const createInitialTables = `
        CREATE TABLE authors (
             id UUID NOT NULL,
             author_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE CHECK (author_name <> ''),
             author_slug VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE CHECK (author_slug <> ''),
             PRIMARY KEY (id)
        );

        CREATE TABLE posts (
             id UUID NOT NULL,
             post VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL CHECK (post<> ''),
             post_slug VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL CHECK (post_slug <> ''),
             author_id UUID NOT NULL,
             PRIMARY KEY (id),
             CONSTRAINT fk_authors FOREIGN KEY(author_id) REFERENCES authors(id)
        );

        CREATE TABLE categories (
             id UUID NOT NULL,
             category_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL CHECK (category_name <> ''),
             category_slug VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL CHECK (category_slug <> ''),
             post_id UUID NOT NULL,
             PRIMARY KEY (id),
             CONSTRAINT fk_posts FOREIGN KEY(post_id) REFERENCES posts(id)
        );

`;
```

Here's the async function where I'm making the insert query:

```
const insertAuthor = async() => {

    try {

        const data       = await fs.readFile( path.join( __dirname + '../../data/data.json' ) );
        const parsedData = JSON.parse( data.toString() );

        const authorID   = short.generate();
        const authorName = parsedData[ 0 ].author;
        const authorSlug = slugify( parsedData[ 0 ].author, {
            strict: true,
            lower: true
        } );

        const insertData = `
            INSERT INTO authors (id, author_name, author_slug) 
            VALUES 
            (${authorID}, ${authorName}, ${authorSlug});
        `;

        await pool.query( insertData );

        console.log( 'Data inserted successfully!' );

    } catch ( e ) {
        console.log( e );
    }
};

insertAuthor();
```

UPDATE--------------------------------------

This is how the Postgres log file looks like:

```
2021-10-18 01:23:16.885 +06 [5964] ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Paton" at character 122
2021-10-18 01:23:16.885 +06 [5964] STATEMENT:  
                INSERT INTO authors (id, author_name, author_slug) 
                VALUES 
                (an3cxZh8ZD3tdtqG4wuwPR, Alan Paton, alan-paton);
```

Comment: Postgres error messages tend to be very specific. Looks like your driver is editing detail out. Take a look at the Postgres log, it should have the information you need. If you don't understand it copy and paste the error message as text as update to your question.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I have updated the OP with the log file data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO authors (id, author_name, author_slug) 
VALUES 
(an3cxZh8ZD3tdtqG4wuwPR, Alan Paton, alan-paton);
```

Your string values are not quoted. It would have to be...

```
INSERT INTO authors (id, author_name, author_slug) 
VALUES 
('an3cxZh8ZD3tdtqG4wuwPR', 'Alan Paton', 'alan-paton');
```

You could add quotes to your query, but don't. Your query as written is insecure and vulnerable to a [SQL injection attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). ***Do not insert values into queries with string concatenation***.

Instead, use [parameters](https://node-postgres.com/features/queries#parameterized-query).

```
const insertSQL = `
  INSERT INTO authors (id, author_name, author_slug) 
  VALUES ($1, $2, $3);
`;
await pool.query( insertSQL, [authorID, authorName, authorSlug] );
```

Postgres will handle the quoting for you. This is safer, more secure, and faster.

---

Note that `an3cxZh8ZD3tdtqG4wuwPR` is not a valid UUID. A UUID is a 128 bit integer often represented as a 32 character hex string.

Note that you also probably want to use [autoincrementing primary keys](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-serial/) instead of generating the ID yourself. For a UUID primary key, load the [uuid-ossp package](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/uuid-ossp.html) and use its UUID function as your default.

```
create extension "uuid-ossp";

create table authors (
  id uuid primary key default uuid_generate_v4(),

  -- There's no point in arbitrarily limiting the size of your text fields.
  -- They will only use as much space as they need.
  author_name text not null unique check (author_name <> ''),
  author_slug text not null unique check (author_slug <> '')
);

insert into authors (author_name, author_slug) 
values ('Alan Paton', 'alan-paton');
```

Comment: Hey man I'm not getting this error: ```error: invalid input syntax for type uuid: "hWBoUWD521QZoEUyV9KGtF"```. I'm using a different package to generate uuid because Postgres' native uuid is too big. I wanted something shorter. Could this be a problem?

Comment: @s.khan That is not a valid UUID. Yes it is a problem. Why do you think it's too big? Do you need UUID primary keys for such a simple schema?

Comment: Is it possible to make the native uuid shorter? And will native uuid solve thiis issue?

Comment: @s.khan A UUID is 128 bits. If you want something shorter, you have to declare your own binary column using [`bytea`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-binary.html). But why?

Comment: Hey. I actually don't need the ids in my app. But I have to I guess because of foreign keys.  But nevermind, I'll just use the native ```gen_random_uuid()``` or the one you suggested.

Comment: @s.khan You need some sort of primary key, but you can just use simple integers. Postgres has the [`serial` data type which automatically increments](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-serial/).

Comment: Thanks so much mate. Big help

Answer (score 0):

In the INSERT query, add the string values in quotes -

```js
const insertData = `
    INSERT INTO authors (id, author_name, author_slug) 
    VALUES 
    ('${authorID}', '${authorName}', '${authorSlug}');`;  // added the quotes
```

Comment: While correct, this is insecure. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: I tried this before. Now I get this error: ```error: invalid input syntax for type uuid: "fyk6q6EsAqhwUQsXiEf6B2"```

Comment: @Schwern, totally agree with you. The data should be sanitized and binded.

Comment: @Vedant Could this be because of author table being a foreign key in posts table?

Comment: @s.khan Like it says, `fyk6q6EsAqhwUQsXiEf6B2` is not a valid UUID.